# printing a bill in jasper report for more then one customer at a time ( on single click ) with different id on sapereate pages in jsf

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

In my jasper report the bill format is the same, ie. single report.jasper file. I want to print more than 1 bill in the same format with different data from the database in one pdf file.

ex. 10 customer bills with different purchase items lists.

Now I have created my simple jasper report with the reference of following

http://javaknowledge.info/calling-jasper-report-from-java-web-application-using-jsf-2-0/

please help me I am new in jasper report and also jsf.

Comment: Do you have any examples of code you are working on - have tried?

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes thanks for your reply  the problem is solved

Comment: in the jasperreport there is option "add report group" and group properties set to "start on new page" then each customer data show on new page of single pdf

Comment: You haven't stated exactly what is going wrong. Have you tried to do this and it failed? Where are the relevant bits of your working code? @NewDev